# How can I add a ch341 driver to a custom linux for Toradex Colibri IMX7d?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, yocto

We are running a java program on a Toradex Colibri IMX7d and we need to communicate through the USB port using a cable that needs the [ch341 serial driver](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/usb/serial/ch341.c).

I attempted to customise a linux kernel bu using the TorizonCore Builder tool but to no avail.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Add `CONFIG_USB_SERIAL_CH341=y` (or `m`, if you are that kind of person) to kernel config?

Comment: Did you try just `modprobe ch341`?

Comment: @skandigraun Would you please elaborate more on that since I'm new to Torizon.

Comment: I haven't used Torizon. Generally you can use the [menuconfig](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev/kernel-dev/common.html#using-menuconfig) in Yocto to configure the kernel, or you could just locate the kernel recipe in your layer, add a new `.cfg` file in the folder with the content of `CONFIG_USB_SERIAL_CH341=y`, add the file to the `SRC_URI` in the recipe, build the image, and see if it explodes.